# What is up with Ansible's runtime environment variables?

Tags: pip, ansible, environment-variables, python-module

can someone kindly explain to me in what kind of environment Ansible runs in? I have been working with this product for the last three months and am finding it very fragile when it comes to using its modules.

I have had issues with python, mysql, and other modules spitting out errors *cant find this* or *cant load that*. I had to rewrite perfectly good examples (even from Ansibles own documentation) and even had to resort running Ansible in a virtualenv so that (for example) *python-package* would be recognized only to have another playbook not recognize it.

For example. I am trying to work with **mysql db modules** and kept getting errors such as these:

```
"msg": "Unable to find any of pip2, pip to use.  pip needs to be installed."

"msg": "The MySQL-python module is required."
```

I did find a solution (after days of struggling with this), but am dumbfounded as to why I need to resort to the below method:

**SOLUTION:**

---

```
- name: Execute task with extended PATH
  shell: echo $PATH
  environment:
    PATH: "/home/vagrant/venv/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"
```

---

I am executing the playbooks locally.

I have pip and mysql-python installed globally:

```
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

[vagrant@controller bin]$ pip show mysql-python
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 9.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

[vagrant@controller bin]$ pip show python
Name: Python
Version: 2.7.4
Summary: A high-level object-oriented programming language
Home-page: http://www.python.org/2.7
Author: Guido van Rossum and the Python community
Author-email: python-dev@python.org
License: PSF license
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
Requires:
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 9.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

[vagrant@controller bin]$ rpm -qa MySQL-python
MySQL-python-1.2.5-1.x86_64

[vagrant@controller bin]$ python27 --version
Python 2.7.4

[vagrant@controller ~]$ which python27
/usr/local/bin/python27
```

I also have the aforementioned installed in my virtualenv from where I am currently running Ansible from:

```
(venv) [vagrant@controller ~]$ pip --version
pip 9.0.3 from /home/vagrant/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

(venv) [vagrant@controller ~]$ python --version
Python 2.7.4

(venv) [vagrant@controller ~]$ which python
~/venv/bin/python

(venv) [vagrant@controller ~]$ pip show mysql-python
Name: MySQL-python
Version: 1.2.5
Summary: Python interface to MySQL
Home-page: https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1
Author: Andy Dustman
Author-email: farcepest@gmail.com
License: GPL
Location: /home/vagrant/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires:
```

I have also specified interpreter and environment variable in the command line as well as in the local inventory file:

```
[all:vars]
deploy_env=local ansible_python_interpreter=/home/vagrant/venv/bin/python2.7

$ansible-playbook -i inventory/local deploy_mysql.yml --diff -e "ansible_python_interpreter=/home/vagrant/venv/bin/python2.7"
```

All necessary packages are installed either globally or in the virtualenv yet cant be found during run-time of the playbook. For pip I was able to get past the error with installing the package like so:

```
- name: Install the Python MySQLB module
  pip: name="{{ item }}"
  extra_args: --index=https://pypi.python.org/pypi/
  with_items: "{{ mysql_dependencies }}"
```

but where did that install to? As mentioned I already had it installed globally and in the virtualenv. While pip seemed to install mysql-python still could not  install.

I have suffered huge delays in delivering my project at work, and would be grateful for an explanation. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: So continuing my work the _solution_ mentioned above got me past this:

`- name: Install MySQL dependencies
  yum: pkg="{{ item }}" state=installed
  with_items: "{{ mysql_dependencies }}"`

but fails later at this block:

`- name: Create a new database
  mysql_db:
    name: "{{ item.value.name }}"
    state: present
    login_host: "{{ item.value.userhost }}"
    login_port: "{{ mysql_port }}"
    login_user: "{{ mysql_root }}"
    login_password: "{{ mysql_root_pass }}"
  with_dict: "{{ databases }}"`

Comment: with this error:

`TASK [mysqldb-setup : Create a new database] *****************************************************************************
failed: [127.0.0.1] (item=........., "msg": "The MySQL-python module is required."}
        to retry, use: --limit @/vagrant/tools/deploy_mysql.retry
`

Comment: Add `-vvv` log of the failing task to the OP.

Comment: Please do not write lumps of unformatted code in comments. Please [edit] the question to include them so they are nicely formatted.

Comment: will do, apologies that 'edit' button is so tiny i keep overlooking it.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible itself, much like python which it is written in, is modular in nature and therefore only requires dependencies when they are actually needed instead of all at once when executed. The dependency chain for the Ansible Core Runtime are outlined in the [requirements file](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/requirements.txt), however each module can potentially add a dependency. When a module adds a dependency, it will be documented as such and you will need to handle that from there. For example, the [os_image module for OpenStack](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/os_image_module.html) requires the `shade` module as listed in the **Requirements** section of it's documentation page.

This brings us to installation methods, you can install Ansible and the dependencies for modules to the system with native system package managers such as `apt`, `yum`, `dnf`, `zypper`, `emerge`, `pacman`, etc. Or you can do so with the python package manager `pip` either in or out of a `virtualenv` and this is done in order to be flexible for the user, but which method is up to the user to choose.

Another thing to keep in mind is **where** the dependencies need to be installed, the Core runtime requirements are needed on the **control** host, but the rest of the dependencies (such as the module dependencies) are required on the remote host.

A common pattern you will see in roles on [Ansible Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/) is to have a set of tasks that install the various dependencies for the rest of the tasks. We do this so that only the requirements that are absolutely needed are installed instead of maintaining the dependency chain for the 2500+ Ansible Modules that come with the standard install of Ansible on every system on your environment.

For your specific scenario, this is all about python paths which you seem to have solved but I am surprised that you had as much trouble as you did because normally you can install things to the python global `site-packages` and it "just works" either via `pip` or your distro's native package manager.

Hopefully this was helpful information.

Happy automating.

Comment: thanks Adam some good reading here. And thanks for letting  me know about galaxy roles resources. for now ill have to skip the trouble spots, fortunately they are not critical yet for my project. Ill have to revisit later when I get some time. thanks!